# form.html.haml not rendering on new.html.haml

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, haml

I'm working from the book 'Agile Web Development with Rails 4' and I'm having some difficulty with my HAML code.

I'm not too sure what I've done wrong, but my form isn't rendering when I go to build a new product. I check the source code and it's not in the HTML either so something is wrong with my code but not sure what. Hopefully someone can help me.

This is my code for Form.html.haml

```
=if @product.errors.any?
  %div{ :id => "error_explanation" }
    %h2
      =pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this product from being saved:

    %ul
    =@product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li 
        =msg

    %div{ :class => "field" }
      =f.label :title
      =f.text_field :title

    %div{ :class => "field" }
      =f.label :description
      =f.text_area :description, rows: 6

    %div{ :class => "field" }
      =f.label :image_url
      =f.text_field :image_url

    %div{ :class => "field" }
      =f.label :price
      =f.text_field :price

    %div{ :class => "actions" }
      =f.submit
```

And this is my New.html.haml

```
%h1 New Product

=render 'form'

=link_to 'Back', products_path
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI: You're kind of misusing HAML. Writting `%div{:class => "actions}"` basically defeats the purpose of HAML. That should simply be written `.actions`, and `%div{ :id => "error_explanation" }` should be `#error_explanation`.

Comment: So @meagar, you mean %div{ #error_explanation}? Sorry, I'm a little bit confused. How can I improve my code?

Comment: No, the entire line would be `#error_explanation`. Here's [a pastebin](http://pastebin.com/74xSfew8). With HAML, you can use `%tag.className` to produce `<tag class="className">`, but if (and only if) the `tag` is a `div`, you can omit the tag entirely and just use `.className`. Ditto `id`, which uses `#` instead of `.` So, `%div(id="what")`, `%div#what` or just `#what` are all the same, as are `%li#what.big` and `%li(id="what" class="big")`.

Comment: Note that you also didn't have your `<ul>`'s body indented.

Comment: Great, I had no idea you could do that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answers provided by *meagar* and *theTRON* as well as your last comment:

Where are you bringing to light the form object? It seems like nowhere, thus you are getting that error. When you bind a form to a model object through the form_for method, it yields a form builder object (the f variable).

Try something like the following:

```
<%= form_for @product, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>
  # your code using f variable ...
<% end %>
```

Let us know if that finally fixed your code.

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed that. Good catch!

Answer (score 0):

Partials need to be named with an `_` prefix.

Your `Form.html.haml` must be called `_form.html.haml`.

Comment: It is _form.html.haml. Is there anything wrong with my HAML code that stops it from rendering?

Comment: Should I just start again?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to ensuring that your form is named `_form.html.haml` you'll need to fix some nesting in your HAML. It should look something like this instead:

```
=if @product.errors.any?
  %div{ :id => "error_explanation" }
    %h2
      =pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error")
      prohibited this product from being saved:

    %ul
    =@product.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
      %li 
        =msg

%div{ :class => "field" }
  =f.label :title
  =f.text_field :title

%div{ :class => "field" }
  =f.label :description
  =f.text_area :description, rows: 6

%div{ :class => "field" }
  =f.label :image_url
  =f.text_field :image_url

%div{ :class => "field" }
  =f.label :price
  =f.text_field :price

%div{ :class => "actions" }
  =f.submit
```

Your indentation that you currently have on your form fields placed it in the scope of the `if @product.errors.any?` block, which means the form would only appear if `@product` had errors.

Comment: Hmm, now I get this error (

Showing depot/app/views/products/_form.html.haml where line #13 raised:

undefined local variable or method `f' for #<#<Class:0x00000101f9d448>:0x000001032ddb70>) after copying and pasting your code